# SSIS Package - detect if Excel is empty

Tags: database, excel, import, ssis, ssms

I have a SSIS Package that imports data from Excel into a database.
Also, in SSMS i have a job that runs the package every **24 hours**. The job fails when the Excel is empty. It can be empty because it contains the updated records from a Share Point list, but for example in weekend the data is not updated.

How can i detect if the Excel file is empty or not? And if it's empty, to stop the running of the package, and if it's not empty to continue to import the data?

[image]

Comment: What is the actual reason the package fails, when it fails, i.e. the error?

Comment: it fails when the Excel contains no data and the package does not have records to import.

Comment: Are you able to use Interop in your environment?  If so, I would start the loop with a c# script that sums the rows in each sheet, then if they are >0 tries to import them.

Comment: Which step fails when the excel is empty?

Comment: Not the package is the problem, the problem is the job that i have set to run every 24 hours (it runs the package every 24 hours). The job, in SSMS, fails when the package tries to import an empty excel. As i said, the excel takes the updated data from a sharepoint list, every 24 hours. If the list isn't updated in those 24 hours, the excel will be empty